# Unable to add a cookie using Selenium & Splinter

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies, splinter

Per below, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this pretty simple usage scenario.

I have script (that I run about once a month) that functionally does the identical thing and which *used* to work as of a month ago.

I'd appreciate any pointers on places to start looking into why this does not work.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 23 2017, 16:49:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from splinter import Browser
>>> chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
>>> browser = Browser('chrome')
>>> browser.cookies.add({'aaa':'bbb'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dummyuser/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/cookie_manager.py", line 28, in add
    self.driver.add_cookie({'name': key, 'value': value})
  File "/Users/dummyuser/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 708, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "/Users/dummyuser/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/dummyuser/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unable to set cookie
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64)
```

Comment: The method `browser.cookies.add` is bound to the current domain which is undefined in your example. You need to set the domain first with `driver.get('http://...')`.

Comment: That fixes it!  Thank you @FlorentB. ! If you move your comment to an answer I'll be able to mark this as resolved & upvote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should open the url first, and load the cookies, then you can open the next url with cookies.you can also open like that if you want open the same url:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'X:\home\xxx\chromedriver.exe')

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
driver.get("https://www.douban.com/")
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get("https://www.douban.com/")
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Florent B. works for me as well, just want to put it into the right place.

`browser.cookies.add` needs to be called after some `browser.visit(...)`

see Florent's comment:

> The method browser.cookies.add is bound to the current domain which is undefined in your example. You need to set the domain first with driver.get('http://...')